# Subsection label appearing within text

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, theorems

I have a document in "book" format (strictly speaking, in an environment defined by the book publisher I am using, the details of which are way beyond my comprehension), and I very much want to have certain paragraphs labeled with the same running count as for theorems, lemmas, etc. but with the numerical label appearing as boldface within the text and *not* set off on its own line.

For example, between Theorem 2.3.7 and Theorem 2.3.9 within section 2.3 of Chapter 2, I'd like to be able to make some intermediate paragraph of my choosing begin with either "2.3.8" in boldface (and ordinary-size font), or perhaps "2.3.8 Blah-blah" in boldface (and ordinary-size font). It is also very important for this command to allow the possibility of using a `\label` command associated to that numerical label "2.3.8" for cross-referencing purposes.

In order to increase the chances of a solution being usable by the book publisher (whose typesetting staff has been unable to provide me with a solution), please try to make answers as simple as possible.

Although I cannot reproduce the publishers proprietary `documentclass` here (it is much too large, and incomprehensible to me), here is a test `.tex` file that I tried based on the comment below suggesting to use the command \paragraph:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A class of groups}

Let $G$ be a group.

\section{A class of subgroups}

Let $H$ be a subgroup.

\paragraph{Refinements}\label{refined} This can be refined.

In \ref{refined} we saw something.

\end{document}
```

The output that I get does not make any numerical label appear in front of "Refinements", and the cross-reference to it at the end produces the numerical label for the section, so it fails miserably.  I want that labelled paragraph to begin with "1.1.1. Refinements" in boldface, and the cross-reference at the end should appear as "In 1.1.1 we saw something".

I should also point out that a version (given to me long ago from a source I cannot remember) *does* work within the `amsart` environment, where the hierarchy shifts by one: instead of `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` it is `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, and the following gives exactly what I seek as a subsubsection (but the publisher told me that they cannot adapt it; hmm, maybe I should specifically ask them to try replacing "subsubsection" with "subsection" below, in case they didn't try that?).

```
\makeatletter

\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%

{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}% default

{\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}% individual control

}

\def\subsubsection@cntformat{{\rm{\textbf{\thesubsubsection.}}}}

\makeatother
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: With other words, you do want a `\subsection` between two theorems, having the number 2.3.8?

Comment: Yes, I should have said that the command \subsection barely fails in my situation precisely because I want the subsection label to appear within the text itself (at the start of a specified paragraph) and not on its own line.  The reason I am unable to provide a MWE is that everything has to work with the publisher's TeX code, and their topmatter is so huge that I am unsure what to extract from it.

Comment: Basically, you need a `\paragraph` rather than `subsection`, if the label number should be a leadin

Comment: I added a suggested solution, however, for lack of time, I could not incorporate your MWE in the meantime

Answer (score 2):

This provides an environment called `\intertheoremremark` similar to  `paragraph` (which is not an environment at all, of course), just with a `subsection` like label and a bold font heading leadin. `\label` works for this.

This uses the `assoccnt` package, which provides a master counter, driving other counters, when stepped, in this case, the `mytheorem` counter.

However, a master counter cannot be driven by another counter, which is driven by the master.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{assoccnt}%




\newcounter{intertheoremremark}


\renewcommand{\theintertheoremremark}{\thesection.\arabic{intertheoremremark}}

\newenvironment{intertheoremremark}[2][]{%
\setcounter{intertheoremremark}{\number\value{mytheorem}}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\refstepcounter{intertheoremremark}%
\large  \textbf{\theintertheoremremark~#2}~
}{}%




\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}

\renewcommand{\themytheorem}{\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{intertheoremremark}{mytheorem}%



\begin{document}

\chapter{Number one}

\section{First section}
\blindtext

\section{Second section}
\blindtext

\begin{mytheorem}{On Brontosaurs} \label{theorem::brontosaurs}
\blindtext
\end{mytheorem}


\begin{intertheoremremark}{Remarks to Theorem \ref{theorem::brontosaurs}} \label{firstremark}%
\blindtext
\end{intertheoremremark}%


\begin{mytheorem}{Other theory on  Brontosaurs} \label{theorem::brontosaurs2}
\blindtext
\end{mytheorem}


\begin{intertheoremremark}{Remarks to Theorem \ref{theorem::brontosaurs2}}%
This is a follow up remark to \ref{firstremark} 
\blindtext
\end{intertheoremremark}%

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

**Edit**

I should add, that I am the author of `assoccnt` package, which is still in a rudimentary version available on CTAN and TeXlive 2014

### Updated version with `\paragraph` coupled to `mytheorem` etc.

This does not use the `assoccnt` package, but uses `paragraph` instead of `intertheoremremark` environment. The behaviour of `stepcounter` is slightly changed, as `assoccnt would do`. The screen shots are nearly the same as in the version above.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{remreset}%


\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}%


\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\@addtoreset{paragraph}{chapter}%
\@addtoreset{mytheorem}{chapter}%
\makeatother




\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}%


\let\standardstepcounter\stepcounter

\renewcommand{\stepcounter}[1]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{paragraph}{%
    \standardstepcounter{mytheorem}%
  }{  \ifstrequal{#1}{mytheorem}{%
      \standardstepcounter{paragraph}%
    }{}}%
  \standardstepcounter{#1}%
}%



\renewcommand{\themytheorem}{\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}}

\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thesection.\arabic{paragraph}.}%





\begin{document}

\chapter{Number one}

\section{First section}
\blindtext

\section{Second section}
\blindtext

\begin{mytheorem}{On Brontosaurs} \label{theorem::brontosaurs}
\blindtext
\end{mytheorem}


\paragraph{Remarks to Theorem \ref{theorem::brontosaurs}} \label{firstremark}%
\blindtext

\begin{mytheorem}{Other theory on  Brontosaurs} \label{theorem::brontosaurs2}
\blindtext
\end{mytheorem}


\paragraph{Remarks to Theorem \ref{theorem::brontosaurs2_again}}%
This is a follow up remark to \ref{secondremark}%
\blindtext


\chapter{Number Two}

\section{First section}
\blindtext

\section{Second section}
\blindtext

\begin{mytheorem}{On Brontosaurs} \label{theorem::brontosaurs_again}
\blindtext
\end{mytheorem}


\paragraph{Remarks to Theorem \ref{theorem::brontosaurs_again}} \label{secondremark}%
\blindtext

\begin{mytheorem}{Other theory on  Brontosaurs} \label{theorem::brontosaurs2_again}
\blindtext
\end{mytheorem}


\paragraph{Remarks to Theorem \ref{theorem::brontosaurs2}}%
This is a follow up remark to \ref{firstremark} 
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am hoping for a procedure which is sufficiently robust that it works even without any Theorems present, just like \subsection. That is, if I want section 2.3 to begin with a subsection 2.3.1 (say after a few introductory sentences) and there is no "Theorem" in the picture at all, I'd still like to be able to make a paragraph that begins with "2.3.1" in boldface at the start (not on its own line), and works with \label. My publisher may frown if I insist on them using a rudimentary version of a package (e.g., assoccnt), so I'll wait to see what other ideas emerge.  Thanks again.

Comment: @BCnrd: The solution just uses one feature of the package. It can be done without the package.

Comment: I have tried it with the lines for \DeclareAssociatedCounters and \usepackage{assoccnt} removed, but it doesn't then make the numbering synced properly (as subsection would); not sure what causes that.  The output is also somewhat bigger font size than the regular text; would be best to be same size as regular text, just like for \subsection.

Comment: @BCnrd: The font size can be changed. I provided another version, without `assoccnt`, using `\paragraph`.

Comment: @BCnrd: Did you see my other version at all?

Comment: Thanks! I'll give the \paragraph version a try in the morning (am tired right now).

Comment: The alternative has a bug: when I make a Chapter 2 and do similar stuff, the first occurrence of \paragraph (which I put in a section 2.1 after a Corollary 2.1.1) comes out as 2.1.5; that "5" is a holdover from Chapter 1, it seems.  Please test your solution with two chapters and see how it comes out. I hope this bug in the counter can be fixed without much trouble so it behaves fully like \subsection. Two other things: the numerical label for \paragraph is missing a period at the end in output, and I have the same question as I posed to egreg in a comment concerning placement of [section].

Comment: The 'bug' is due to the fact, that there was no request, that chapters should reset `theorems`. In addition, I find your requests very demanding for a question which is not really clearly posted!

Answer (score 2):

Define a new theorem environment.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{interthm}[thm]{\ignorespaces}% theorem label is empty

\begin{document}

\chapter{A class of groups}

Let $G$ be a finite group.

\section{A class of subgroups}

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

\begin{thm}\label{lagrange}
The order of $H$ divides the order of $G$.
\end{thm}

\begin{interthm}\label{lagrange-comment}
Theorem~\ref{lagrange} is credited to Lagrange and can be
inverted for abelian groups.
\end{interthm}

\begin{thm}\label{inverse-lagrange}
If $G$ is abelian and $k$ is a divisor of the order
of $G$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $k$.
\end{thm}

In \ref{lagrange-comment} we saw something.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make it into a command by using an `\everypar` trick; use it only at the outer level.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\newcommand{\interthm}{%
  \par\refstepcounter{thm}%
  \everypar{{\setbox0=\lastbox}\textbf{\thethm.} \everypar{}}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A class of groups}

Let $G$ be a finite group.

\section{A class of subgroups}

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

\begin{thm}\label{lagrange}
The order of $H$ divides the order of $G$.
\end{thm}

\interthm\label{lagrange-comment}
Theorem~\ref{lagrange} is credited to Lagrange and can be
inverted for abelian groups.

\begin{thm}\label{inverse-lagrange}
If $G$ is abelian and $k$ is a divisor of the order
of $G$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $k$.
\end{thm}

In \ref{lagrange-comment} we saw something.

\end{document}
```

Note that, in this case, no additional vertical space below the numbered paragraph can be set automatically.

Comment: Awesome, this seems to do the trick!  Let me fiddle around with it for some time.  Strictly speaking, I'd love to have one slightly "better" feature, in the spirit of \subsection:  can the command be designed to not require a \begin{...} and \end{...} part, just a single command right at the spot where I want the numerical label to appear, and not needing to select an \end{...} location?  (The reason I ask is that I am going to have to tell the publisher what to do, and to the extent I can minimize what they have to do it will be better.)

Comment: @BCnrd: you could wrap the environment in another macro ;-)

Comment: @BCnrd I added an alternative solution

Comment: @egreg: Thanks very much! I'll give it a try in the morning (right now I am tired after a long day).

Comment: @egreg: The last line of the output reads as "1.1.3.  In 1.1.2 we saw something" with 1.1.3 showing there in boldface (and without indentation). I then duplicated the final line of .tex code (before \end{document}) and there appears a  repetition of the same line of text at the end of the output except *without* the "1.1.3" repeated in front and *with* an indentation. Is there a way to fix this bug? Also, my original .tex code used \newtheorem{thm}[section]{Theorem}, but that doesn't work with the solution; is there a way to make it work with that (to minimize what the publisher must change)?

Comment: @BCnrd Sorry, but I get nothing strange, in particular no duplication. I'd say that `\newtheorem{thm}[section]{Theorem}` is wrong, unless you want to step the section number for each theorem

Comment: @egreg: Huh, so you don't get a repetition of "1.1.3" in front of the last line of output of the .tex code as you wrote it?  (I cut-and-pasted your code into a file on my laptop and ran it, getting that glitch in the output. Then I tested it against duplicating the final line of code, etc.)  I am puzzled by the difference in outputs.  I am also now puzzled as to why \newtheorem{thm}[section]{Theorem} works well for me (without stepping the section number for each theorem)...